# Unwanted white-space between elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

Why does the following CSS code create white-space between the end of the blue (middle) element and the last (right) element?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sv">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>A test page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .tte {
        width: 20%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .as {
        width: 60%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .ground {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .left {
        left: 0;
    }
    .right {
        right: 0;
    }
    .middle {
        left: 20%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tte ground left"></div>
    <div class="tte ground right"></div>
    <div class="as ground middle"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect the code to create two green block elements, each with width 20% and height 50%, aligned in the left top corner and the right top corner respectively, and a blue block element aligned right in the middle with width 60% and the same height. But there is noticeable white-space between the end of the blue element and the beginning of the last (right) green element. Why?

- Using Safari 7.0.1 on Mavericks

Comment: I'm not seeing a white space in this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/RGZZL/ what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of Safari on Mac OS X 10.9.1. Safari shows a noticeable white-space, I've tried in Chrome and Firefox too though the white-space there is not as noticeable.

Comment: Remove the `right:0` and see what happens.

Comment: maybe you could size your element only via coordonates :.left {left:0;right:80%;} .right {left:80%;right:0;} .middle {left:20%;right:20%;} so values are the same, even if width of screen is odd or even .

Comment: It seems to depend on the current size of the browser window. Sometimes there is no white-space, other times there are. It may be a bug in the browser.

Comment: this is the reason why i advise you to use coordonates instead :)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. It works perfectly in Firefox, however.

Comment: not sure but usually I surround `position: relative` around `position: absolute`, or is `<body>` inherentily relative positioned?  You can try putting the 3 divs inside a `<div style="position:relative">` just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: The three blocks disappear if I try using a relatively positioned wrapper. Or have I done it wrong?

Comment: @MånsNilsson If you want it to work with `position: relative` you need to add `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }` to your css. Otherwise it does not know what 100% is since the parent (html body) does not have a set size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Have you tried using display:table-cell? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RGZZL/1/

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}

.left, .right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:20%;
    background:green;
}
.middle {
    display:table-cell;
    width:60%;
    background:blue;
}
```

--

<s>I don't see the issue you're talking about, but try this. Put a wrapper around the divs, and set the font-size and line-height to zero on that one. Then reset the font-size and line-height for the three divs inside. I've found that sometimes a space in your code can make the browser think you have a space character in there which adds whitespace.</s>

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help either. I tried to do relative positioning on all three blocks inside a relatively positioned wrapper. It works perfectly on both Chrome and Firefox, so I think the problem has something to do with either Safari or its WebKit rendering engine. It doesn't scale correctly when using percentage values for width and/or height. Searching at Google, it appears to be related to round-offs of the widths of each element. See http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/.